# Is SUDS affected by Firewall?

Tags: python, suds

I am trying to get suds to connect to ANYTHING.  This is my first time using it.  Every url I put in returns me an error.  Here is my code; copied almost exactly from a different thread.

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAcceleration.asmx?WSDL"
client = Client(url)
print client
```

and it always returns me an error at:

```
client = Client(url)
urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 8] node name or service name not known
```

I am curious if this is because I am behind a pretty hefty corporate firewall and if anyone knew a way to get around it sans bugging sysadmins.
The url that I am using is valid.
I can connect to stuff on my computer no problem, just can't seem to get out of the system.

Thanks

*Edit: Using the WSDL on my local directory throws me the same error when I try to call methods.
Using a website that is within the firewall sends me an error of:

```
urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 146] Connection refused
```

I assume this is because it requires password authentication.  I have been trying/playing with proxy settings but cannot seem to make any progress.

I have seen a couple threads on other forums of people with similar problems, but none of them had solutions yet.

Comment: Can you access that URL/domain in a browser?

Comment: yes, no problem connecting to it.

Comment: Your proxy settings or lack thereof could also be an issue. (And note: The proxy settings are very naive in python!)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there might be a restriction on what programs can reach the Network. This is typically done to prevent Virus and Worms from getting on your machine and then going out to the Internet to pull in a payload or receive more instructions.

Also, you mentioned a proxy. You may have to configure your program to use the proxy before it can reach the Internet.